# My iPhone says I'm on the wrong side of the world

Tags: ios, compass

My compass app is reporting that I am X degrees north, X degrees E, however I am most certainly west of greenwich (Basically I am closer to USA than greenwich).

Is this a known bug, I assume that the standard of writing positions is not backward, as I am in the northern hemisphere and it states I'm north.

It's not that it's got the wrong position, but the wrong side of the greenwich meridian, as the degrees, minutes and seconds are correct (according to google maps), it's only it says `E` instead of `W`?

Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the reports in [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/11485596?messageID=11485596) Apple discussion forum, this is definitely a bug.

As stated in the forum thread, you should [report it to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html).